# Strange behavior performing library functions on STDOUT and STDIN's file descriptors

Tags: c, unix, io, file-descriptor

Throughout my years as a C programmer, I've always been confused about the standard stream file descriptors. Some places, like Wikipedia<sup>[[1]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29)</sup>, say:

> In the C programming language, the standard input, output, and error streams are attached to the existing Unix file descriptors 0, 1 and 2 respectively.

This is backed up by [`unistd.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/unistd.h.html):

```
/* Standard file descriptors.  */
#define STDIN_FILENO    0       /* Standard input.  */
#define STDOUT_FILENO   1       /* Standard output.  */
#define STDERR_FILENO   2       /* Standard error output.  */
```

However, this code (on any system):

```
write(0, "Hello, World!\n", 14);
```

Will print `Hello, World!` (and a newline) to `STDOUT`. This is odd because `STDOUT`'s file descriptor is supposed to be 1. `write`-ing to file descriptor 1
also prints to `STDOUT`.

Performing an `ioctl` on file descriptor 0 changes standard input<sup>[[2]](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/_kbhit_for_Linux.shtml)</sup>, and on file descriptor 1 changes standard output. However, performing [`termios` functions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/termios) on either 0 or 1 changes standard input<sup>[[3]](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112/blob/master/stdin.c)[[4]](http://www.minek.com/files/unix_examples/raw.html)</sup>.

I'm very confused about the behavior of file descriptors 1 and 0. Does anyone know why:

- `write`ing to 1 or 0 writes to standard output?
- Performing `ioctl` on 1 modifies standard output and on 0 modifies standard input, but performing `tcsetattr`/`tcgetattr` on either 1 or 0 works for standard input?

Comment: Why in the world do you think it is writing anything to stdout?  It is writing to your terminal.  The stdout of your process may be associated with your terminal, but they aren't the same thing.  Don't conflate the two.  In your case, stdin is also associated with the terminal so it's not surprising that writes to stdin show up on the terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by reviewing some of the key concepts involved:

- **File description**

  In the operating system kernel, each file, pipe endpoint, socket endpoint, open device node, and so on, has a *file description*.  The kernel uses these to keep track of the position in the file, the flags (read, write, append, close-on-exec), record locks, and so on.

  The file descriptions are internal to the kernel, and do not belong to any process in particular (in typical implementations).
- **File descriptor**

  From the process viewpoint, file descriptors are integers that identify open files, pipes, sockets, FIFOs, or devices.

  The operating system kernel keeps a table of descriptors for each process. The file descriptor used by the process is simply an index to this table.

  The entries to in the file descriptor table refer to a kernel file description.

Whenever a process uses [`dup()` or `dup2()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup2.2.html) to duplicate a file descriptor, the kernel only duplicates the entry in the file descriptor table for that process; it does not duplicate the file description it keeps to itself.

When a process forks, the child process gets its own file descriptor table, but the entries still point to the exact same kernel file descriptions. (This is essentially a [shallow copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shallow_copy#Shallow_copy), will all file descriptor table entries being references to file descriptions. The references are copied; the referred to targets remain the same.)

When a process sends a file descriptor to another process via an Unix Domain socket ancillary message, the kernel actually allocates a new descriptor on the receiver, and copies the file description the transferred descriptor refers to.

It all works very well, although it is a bit confusing that *"file descriptor"* and *"file description"* are so similar.

What does all that have to do with the effects the OP is seeing?

Whenever new processes are created, it is common to open the target device, pipe, or socket, and `dup2()` the descriptor to standard input, standard output, and standard error. This leads to all three standard descriptors referring to the same *file description*, and thus whatever operation is valid using one file descriptor, is valid using the other file descriptors, too.

This is most common when running programs on the console, as then the three descriptors all definitely refer to the same file description; and that file description describes the slave end of a pseudoterminal character device.

Consider the following program, **run.c**:

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

static void wrerrp(const char *p, const char *q)
{
    while (p < q) {
        ssize_t  n = write(STDERR_FILENO, p, (size_t)(q - p));
        if (n > 0)
            p += n;
        else
            return;
    }
}

static inline void wrerr(const char *s)
{
    if (s)
        wrerrp(s, s + strlen(s));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd;

    if (argc < 3) {
        wrerr("\nUsage: ");
        wrerr(argv[0]);
        wrerr(" FILE-OR-DEVICE COMMAND [ ARGS ... ]\n\n");
        return 127;
    }

    fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666);
    if (fd == -1) {
        const char *msg = strerror(errno);
        wrerr(argv[1]);
        wrerr(": Cannot open file: ");
        wrerr(msg);
        wrerr(".\n");
        return 127;
    }

    if (dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO) != STDIN_FILENO ||
        dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO) != STDOUT_FILENO) {
        const char *msg = strerror(errno);
        wrerr("Cannot duplicate file descriptors: ");
        wrerr(msg);
        wrerr(".\n");
        return 126;
    }
    if (dup2(fd, STDERR_FILENO) != STDERR_FILENO) {
        /* We might not have standard error anymore.. */
        return 126;
    }

    /* Close fd, since it is no longer needed. */
    if (fd != STDIN_FILENO && fd != STDOUT_FILENO && fd != STDERR_FILENO)
        close(fd);

    /* Execute the command. */
    if (strchr(argv[2], '/'))
        execv(argv[2], argv + 2);  /* Command has /, so it is a path */
    else
        execvp(argv[2], argv + 2); /* command has no /, so it is a filename */

    /* Whoops; failed. But we have no stderr left.. */
    return 125;
}
```

It takes two or more parameters. The first parameter is a file or device, and the second is the command, with the rest of the parameters supplied to the command. The command is run, with all three standard descriptors redirected to the file or device named in the first parameter. You can compile the above with gcc using e.g.

```
gcc -Wall -O2 run.c -o run
```

Let's write a small tester utility, **report.c**:

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char    buffer[16] = { "\n" };
    ssize_t result;
    FILE   *out;

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nUsage: %s FILENAME\n\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    out = fopen(argv[1], "w");
    if (!out)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    result = write(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, 1);
    if (result == -1) {
        const int err = errno;
        fprintf(out, "write(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, 1) = -1, errno = %d (%s).\n", err, strerror(err));
    } else {
        fprintf(out, "write(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, 1) = %zd%s\n", result, (result == 1) ? ", success" : "");
    }

    result = read(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, 1);
    if (result == -1) {
        const int err = errno;
        fprintf(out, "read(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, 1) = -1, errno = %d (%s).\n", err, strerror(err));
    } else {
        fprintf(out, "read(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, 1) = %zd%s\n", result, (result == 1) ? ", success" : "");
    }

    result = read(STDERR_FILENO, buffer, 1);
    if (result == -1) {
        const int err = errno;
        fprintf(out, "read(STDERR_FILENO, buffer, 1) = -1, errno = %d (%s).\n", err, strerror(err));
    } else {
        fprintf(out, "read(STDERR_FILENO, buffer, 1) = %zd%s\n", result, (result == 1) ? ", success" : "");
    }

    if (ferror(out))
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    if (fclose(out))
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It takes exactly one parameter, a file or device to write to, to report whether writing to standard input, and reading from standard output and error work. (We can normally use `$(tty)` in Bash and POSIX shells, to refer to the actual terminal device, so that the report is visible on the terminal.) Compile this one using e.g.

```
gcc -Wall -O2 report.c -o report
```

Now, we can check some devices:

```
./run /dev/null    ./report $(tty)
./run /dev/zero    ./report $(tty)
./run /dev/urandom ./report $(tty)
```

or on whatever we wish. On my machine, when I run this on a file, say

```
./run some-file ./report $(tty)
```

writing to standard input, and reading from standard output and standard error all work -- which is as expected, as the file descriptors refer to the same, readable and writable, file description.

The conclusion, after playing with the above, is that there **is no strange behaviour here at all**. It all behaves exactly as one would expect, if *file descriptors* as used by processes are simply references to operating system internal *file descriptions*, and standard input, output, and error descriptors are `dup`licates of each other.

Answer (score 6):

I guess it is because in my Linux, both `0` and `1` are by default opened with *read/write* to the `/dev/tty` which is the controlling terminal of the process. So indeed it is possible to even *read* from `stdout`.

However this breaks as soon as you *pipe* something in or out:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    errno = 0;
    write(0, "Hello world!\n", 14);
    perror("write");
}
```

and run with

```
% ./a.out 
Hello world!
write: Success
% echo | ./a.out
write: Bad file descriptor
```

`termios` functions always work on the actual underlying terminal object, so it doesn't matter whether `0` or `1` is used for as long as it is opened to a tty.

Comment: If we delve in to the details, it's actually a bit more interesting than that, even. Each *file descriptor* number refers to a kernel structure called *file description* in Linux and Unixy systems. `dup()` creates a new file descriptor (by duplicating the old one); the new refers to the very same *file description*. In a terminal application, all three standard streams are `dup2()`'ed from the pseudoterminal, and all three behave the exact same way (that is, you can write to `STDIN_FILENO`, and read from `STDOUT_FILENO` and `STDERR_FILENO`). Yet, this is not limited to pseudoterminals: [...]

Comment: [...] It can/will happen whenever standard input and output/error originate from the same, writable *file description* -- be that a pseudoterminal (tty), file, or even a socket. If there is interest, I can provide a POSIX-portable example program that can be used for testing and exploration.

Comment: @NominalAnimal you should write an answer then. I started with *I guess* because I don't have any authoritative source on how this happens, and which of it is POSIX and which is just Linux, beyond `dup2` of course.