# C read() function difficulty understanding file descriptor

Tags: c, posix

I'm having difficulity understanding the `read` function in C.

```
len = read(fd, buf, 32);
```

when I assign `fd` as 0,1,2 and run the program, its basically doing the same thing, can someone tell me what difference does this make?

Comment: Do you know what the fd 0, 1 , 2 means?

Comment: "basically doing the same thing" -- What is it doing? Is it doing what you expect?

Comment: He means file descriptor i think.

Comment: I assume posix `read()` (added tag), so 0 is `stdin`'s fd, 1 is for `stdout` and 2 `stderr`. `read()` only makes sense with `0`, the others are output streams.

Comment: If you read this article you might understand the differences between 0, 1 and 2 in this case. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor

Comment: hmm i didnt understand what it does basically ... can you elaborate more? its doing the same thing , len equals to the length of string i wrote when i run the program

Comment: This was just asked yesterday...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your question it is why nothing changes if you read from file descriptors 0, 1, 2.

In a normal program the file descriptor 0 is stdin, 1 is stdout and 2 is stderr. stdin is where you should read your input, 1 is where you should write your output and 2 is where you should write your error messages.

It is not uncommon that all three file descriptors may point to the same underlying file (a file can also be the console, network connection, etc.) behind the scenes. If you're just running your program from the command line this is actually quite likely. In that case you may be able to read from all of them and get the exact same result.

But. Then you decide that you want to save the output of the program in a file and run it like this: `program > output`. Now file descriptor 1 is no longer pointing to the same file as stdin and your program would break. Same thing happens if you point stderr to some error logging facility. Or get the input from a file or a pipe. Or run the program in some debuggers. Or a different terminal. This is why you should only read from 0 and no other file descriptors, even if you might get away with it sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

[read()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) attempts to read up to count bytes from file descriptor fd.

```
fd = 0
fd = 1
fd = 2
```

Is reading from different file descriptors. The difference is, you are reading from different files, and the data read into the buffer is different.

What is the difference in reading from `Book A` and reading from `Book B` ? it is the same process of reading a book... it is the content that changes.

Comment: Different file descriptors may refer to the same file

Comment: wait .. if im running it on cmd, and its asking for input, what "book" is it? sorry im a newbie in this thing , i only do competitive programming ...

Comment: @眠りネロク true, but lets assume it's different files.

Comment: @XiangRamadhan, reading from stdin, will read data you type in the `cmd`. For simplicity forget `0 1 2`, think as if you are opening two file.. (they will have different file descriptors). if one file content is `blabla` and the other one is `foo`, and you want to read 2 bytes, the first one will return `bl` and the other one `fo`.

Comment: what? so what does fd do in this ? if i assign fd into  more than 2 it would not take any input .

Comment: @XiangRamadhan linux limits the number of file descriptors a process can have. So you can't assign any `fd`. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256599/what-are-file-descriptors-explained-in-simple-terms it might help.

Comment: still unclear :( ... so why is read(2,buf,32) taking something from stdin?

Comment: @XiangRamadhan try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45536707/strange-behavior-performing-library-functions-on-stdout-and-stdins-file-descrip

Comment: this and @Art comment answered it , thanks so much