# how can we read the content of stdin stdout stderr in c?

Tags: c, operating-system

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<fcntl.h>

void main()
{
    int stdout_bk,stdin_bk,stderr_bk;
    char x[100],y[100],z[100];
    stdout_bk=dup(fileno(stdout));
    stdin_bk=dup(fileno(stdin));
    stderr_bk=dup(fileno(stderr));
    read(stdin_bk,x,100);
    read(stdout_bk,y,100);
    read(stderr_bk,z,100);
    printf("\n%s",x);
    printf("\n%s",y);
    printf("\n%s",z);
}
```

I have already tried this but, I did not get the proper answer. How the buffer works while running any C program?

Comment: `stdout` and `stderr` are **output** streams. Even if your system allows reading from them, I have no idea what you expect to find there.

Comment: Do you mean this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45536707/strange-behavior-performing-library-functions-on-stdout-and-stdins-file-descrip

Comment: Further to what @FelixPalmen said: `stdout` and `stderr` are *already being read* - by the parent process (e.g. the shell that launched your program).  You can't also read them, any more than you could drink from the same straw as someone else at the same time.

Comment: @JohnZwinck the shell / parent process is unlikely to be at the reading end, more likely e.g. a terminal emulator through a `pty` device.

Comment: @FelixPalmen *`stdout` and `stderr` are **output** streams. Even if your system allows reading from them, I have no idea what you expect to find there.*  [A pony, perhaps?](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2013/12/13/pony-somewhere/)