# read skipping number input

Tags: c, unix

When I use the below code, I'm *unable to enter the second number*. The program is not waiting to get the second number, it jumps to `"Enter third number: "` after I type first number. How do I make my code wait for me to enter the second number? I tried using the `wait` function but it's not working.

```
#include <unistd.h>

void    ft_putchar(char c);
void    ft_putnbr(int nbr);
void    ft_putstr(char *str);

void    ft_putchar(char c)
{
    write(1, &c, 1);
}

void    ft_putnbr(int nbr)
{
    if (nbr > 9)
        ft_putnbr(nbr / 10);
            ft_putchar('0' + nbr % 10);

}

void    ft_putstr(char *str)
{
    int i;

    i = 0;
    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        ft_putchar(str[i]);
        i++;
    }

}

int     main(void)
{   
    int first_number;
    int second_number;
    int third_number;

    ft_putstr("Enter first number: ");
    read(1, &first_number, 1);
    ft_putchar('\n');

    ft_putstr("Enter second number: ");
    read(1, &second_number, 1);
    ft_putchar('\n');

    ft_putstr("Enter third number: ");
    read(1, &third_number, 1);
    ft_putchar('\n');

    ft_putstr("The numbers are: ");
    ft_putchar(first_number);
    ft_putchar(second_number);
    ft_putchar(third_number);
    ft_putchar('\n');

    return (0);
}
```

Output:

```
Enter first number: 4

Enter second number: 
Enter third number: 3

The numbers are: 4
3
```

Comment: read() should probably be scanf("%d", &first_number)

Comment: You can't (directly) use `read` to read an integer in ascii.

Comment: If you enter a single digit and then read that digit there is probably a newline still waiting to be read. As shown by the extra spacing in the output.

Comment: Side-note: [Reading from *stdout* is a complicated, strange thing to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45536707/strange-behavior-performing-library-functions-on-stdout-and-stdins-file-descrip).

Answer (score 1):

Your calls to [`read`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) are reading *one byte* at a time, and placing that data in the first byte of a (minimum) `4` byte object: an `int`. The value you are receiving is not one of the integer values from `0-9`, but rather the encoding value of the *characters* `'0'` through `'9'` (in ASCII that's the integer values `48-57`).

The value of this `int` is then *coerced* into a `char` when you pass it to `ft_putchar`.

The reason you see the correct digits displayed at all is because your machine is little-endian, that is to say that the *least-significant byte* is stored in the lowest address in memory. This matters as when you coerce an `int` into a `char` all bytes other than the LSB are discarded. (If your machine was big-endian you would see garbage printed to the screen, since the LSB was never initialized.)

Ultimately, this program does not read "numbers", it reads characters one-by-one. Pressing the <kbd>RETURN</kbd> key sends any pending characters, *as well as the newline character* (`'\n'`), as input to your program. As such you are storing the value of `'\n'` in the first byte of `second_number`. Notice the newline between your two outputted digits.

To further illustrate what's happening, simply try typing letters and other characters into this program. Or try typing three digits on the first line to really see what's happening - it will just 'work'.

On the whole, this is simply the wrong way to read integer values.

While you could implement integer reading and writing using [`read`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) and [`write`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html), they are rather low level routines and you'd essentially be recreating functionality found in the standard library of C.

I would encourage you to start with simpler functions like those found in the [`stdio`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io) library. [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), and [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) are a good base to work with. There are endless examples of this out there, here is another basic one:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {              
    int number;
    char input[32];    
                   
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    
    if (fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin))        
        if (sscanf(input, "%d", &number) == 1)
            printf("You entered: %d\n", number);
    
    puts("Goodbye."); 
}
```

---

> I tried using the `wait` function but it's not working.

That is because [`wait`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) is for retrieving information about state changes in child processes, and has nothing to do with reading or writing from file descriptors. You'll really want to pay close attention to the details of the manual pages for the functions you are trying to use.